# c# compare 2 files - create and update functions

Tags: c#, xml, filesystems, filestream

It is my first time to write code to function file operations. I need to compare old file with a new file. If the old file name is equal to a new file name, it needs to be overwritten (update). If not equal, creating a new file name. How to do this in a simple and best way?

```
public void FileCreateOrOverwritten(string file)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            if (file == newFile)
            {
                //how to replace old file with a new one with new data (xml document)
                //need to use filestream
            }
            else
            {
                //how to create a new file with new data (xml document)
            }

        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2281769/706456) shall solve it for you.

Comment: You mention xml - consider serialising like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220973/c-sharp-xml-serialization-deserialization

Answer (score 0):

To (over)write a file,

```
using (var writer = File.CreateText(file))
{
    for (...)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(...);
    }
}
```

You don't then need to decide if you have an old one to over-write or a new one to create. 
From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx)

> "This method is equivalent to the StreamWriter(String, Boolean)
>   constructor overload with the append parameter set to false. If the
>   file specified by path does not exist, it is created. If the file does
>   exist, its contents are overwritten"

If you are new to this, note the `using`

Comment: And the reason why `using` should be used, is that it guarantees that the `writer`'s Dispose method is called after the program exits the `using` block

Comment: well... i dont like this way. i think maybe it is better to remove the old file first then move the new file in if their file names are equal...

Comment: @user1358072 Do it however you want. The over-write in effect removes the old one for you, but if you'd rather do it yourself that's odd but it's your code